# Is it possible, using Entity Framework 4, to have the primary key be named something different on the object than in the table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Let's say that hypothetically I have a table called `Products` with a primary key called `ProductID`.  Is it possible to have my entity class (using Entity Framework 4 Code First) have a property called `ID` instead of `ProductID`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Just edit the name of the property in the designer.

**UPDATE:**
This is also supported in Code First. See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

Comment: Sorry - I should've clarified.  I'm using EF4 Code First with an existing database, like ScottGu posted about here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Comment: If you doing Code first Id is also allowed such as ProductId. Do you have a existing Database ?

Comment: @benjy: In the article you linked, this is already mentioned with a link to another article: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx